# Cloudify: bootstrap-localcloud: operation failed in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cloudify

I am new to the cloudify, and I get a problem on the cloudify installation, which is shown below

```
STARTING CLOUDIFY MANAGEMENT
Operation failed. org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.CLIException: Error while starting agent. Please make sure that another agent
is not already running. Command executed: cmd.exe /c @call D:\Program Files\gigaspaces-cloudify-2.2.0-ga\bin\"gs.bat" start startL
H startGSM startESM startGSA gsa.global.lus 0 gsa.lus 0 gsa.gsc 0 gsa.global.gsm 0 gsa.gsm_lus 0 gsa.global.esm 0 gsa.esm 0 >nul 2
>&1
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.runCommand(LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.java:1286)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.runGsAgentOnLocalHost(LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.
java:746)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.startManagementOnLocalhostAndWaitInternal(LocalhostGr
idAgentBootstrapper.java:794)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.startLocalCloudOnLocalhostAndWait(LocalhostGridAgentB
ootstrapper.java:327)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.BootstrapLocalCloud.doExecute(BootstrapLocalCloud.java:100)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.AbstractGSCommand.execute(AbstractGSCommand.java:79)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:221)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:191)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:89)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.GigaShellMain.main(GigaShellMain.java:122)
```

I certainly don't have a second agent running, the config of my computer is windows 7, 64bit. I have no idea what is the problem, even I have tried to run it as administrator, but doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Do you have a JDK installed (Not a JRE)? Is JAVA_HOME configured correctly?
- Is the hostname of your machine set up correctly (can you ping hostname?)

To debug Cloudify local cloud issues, have a look at the /logs directory. There should be several log files there. Look for the one with the characters 'gsa' in it in particular.
If you don't find anything useful, zip the files and upload them here.

You can also open a support case on the Cloudify support forum: https://cloudifysource.zendesk.com/forums/20582412-cloudify-users